# Left to right slider is not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is my link http://codepen.io/sanand29/pen/mKkvw

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
```

```
    <title>Ionic Template</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.8/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.8/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <ion-view class="pane"></ion-view>
    <ion-side-menus>
      <ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon-round"
              menu-toggle="left"
            ></button>
           <h1 class="title">Welcome</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
         <ion-list>
            <ion-item href="#/tab/admission-information" class="item item-icon-right ">
              Admission-Information
              <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#/tab/contacts" class="item item-icon-right "> 
              Contacts
              <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#/tab/program-details" class="item item-icon-right "> 
              Program details
              <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#/tab/tution-fees" class="item item-icon-right "> 
              Tution fees
              <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#/tab/financial-aids" class="item item-icon-right "> 
              Financial Aids
              <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#/tab/faqs" class="item item-icon-right "> 
              FAQs
              <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Left menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
      </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  });</script>
```

the navigation bars that i have given, on clicking them its not sliding from left to right. I have given the slider class correctly i think,,I can't find out my fault. Kindly show in fiddle or code pen. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which buttons do you want to add and which ones are not showing? I just checked your codepen. Everything according to your code, is alright.

Comment: even then its not coming,, m trying to use tabs instead of buttons which will slide left to write on clicking,, can u help me in that by giving an example,, m a begginer in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the view to slide in when a tab is clicked you should use an `animation` class on an [ion-nav-view](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/).

If you want to get the view to slide in when the user slides across the view you should use an [ion-slide-box](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/)

Comment: can i use normal html5 tags to give square buttons??